# Check if the current Session has expired in ASIHTTPREQUEST

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

How can i check if the session that i have created using following code

```
NSURL *myWebserverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:XMLURLAddress];

ASIHTTPRequest *request=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:myWebserverURL];

[request setTimeOutSeconds:3600];
```

has expired? My scenario is that when my session is created and if the wifi is turned on and after a minute or two wifi is activated again, the session is expired. So how can i know that this session has expired?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: `ASIHTTPRequest` is dead. If you're looking for something similar use `AFNetworking`, or check iOS7 brand new `NSURLSession`.

But for `ASIHTTPRequest`: Did you set the following completion blocks?

```
- (void)setCompletionBlock:(ASIBasicBlock)aCompletionBlock;
- (void)setFailedBlock:(ASIBasicBlock)aFailedBlock;
```

Another thing what might help you is adding any `Reachability` implementation to your project, so you can monitor the current connection type.